# How to check for uncaught exceptions?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, resharper

In Visual Studio 2013 with Resharper, is there some way to check, if i have any uncaught exceptions in my project?

Comment: Not sure what the close voters were thinking, but to anyone reading this: a question starting "In Visual Studio 2013 with Resharper" is pretty explicitly about "tools used primarily for programming"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Agent Johnson plugin for Resharper which has static exception checks. See the following link:

https://code.google.com/p/agentjohnsonplugin/